# Angular 2 and DOM navigation

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 how do you, in general, cope with DOM navigation, or do you just rely on JQuery or a JQuery like helper?

e.g. What's an Angular equivalent of closest and prevAll and situations where querySelectorAll isn't sufficient

I am aware that I could just write Javascript to do this

Example. I had a button which changed the text in a textbox

```
// Approach 1, change via a model property
FillTextBoxViaProperty(e)
{
    this.OtherProperty = "From textbox, but via the property"
}

// Approach 2, change via DOM manipulation
FillTextBoxDirectly(e)
{
    var elem = jQuery(e.srcElement).prevAll('input');   

    elem.val("From textbox directly");
}
```

From the comments it seems that approach (1) is the way to go

Comment: what's your use-case to manipulate existing dom over emitting new dom?

Comment: I'm at the learning stage for Angular 2, I wanted to click a button and manipulate a textbox about 5 elements up. Not rocket science, but I can't ask for opinions as those posts tend to get deleted here

Comment: You need to learn angular. Trying to apply your usual jquery recipes with angular is a dead end. That's not how angular is supposed to be used. In angular, you don't manipulate the DOM (except in exceptional situations, and in directives only). You manipulate the model, and only the model. The DOM automatically adapts itself to the changes in the model, thanks to directives in the template.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's actually the kind of opinion I was after. I'll add more detail to the question to explain the two approaches I was looking at

Comment: Yes, the first approach is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the first approach. Also, you might want to have a look at redux. to better manage the way how components receive updates (for Angular 2 see https://github.com/ngrx/store )

Comment: Absolutely the first approach, I would highly suggest walking through the angular 2 tutorial instead of trying to build an app from the ground up without getting a feel for how the framework is intended to be used. This is because the Angular approach to client side development is very, very different from jQuery's methodology.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: I'm making my way through the tutorial now. The biggest stumbling block to learning Angular 2 is that it's changed so much over time that when you want to read around a topic you find lots of now obsolete links